# How can I allow a user to query a view but not the underlying table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, permissions, view

I have searched for this question but cannot find an answer.  Or, the answers I have found have been related to SQL Server.  This is for `MySQL 5.x`.

Anyway, say I have a table called `Employees` and in that table, I have various columns like:

```
id, lastname, firstname, salary, ssn, hiredate
```

Now, I have some users that need to be able to select from the **VIEW** but not the **TABLE**.

For example:

```
--user a
select * from employee_view;

--shows:
id, lastname, firstname, hiredate

--user a
select * from employee;   // access denied  (didn't use view)
```

Then I have an `HR User`:

```
--HR user
select * from employee_view;

-- shows:
id, lastname, firstname, ssn, salary, hiredate

-- HR user
select * from employee;  // access denied (didn't use view)
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Run `SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user='$youruser';` and edit your question with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

First, I created an account that ONLY had permissions to certain columns (not all).  I then created a view for those columns and used the user as the definer.

Then, I created another test account and ONLY gave them permissions to that view.

So the test user could not see the underlying table but only the view and columns.

Works great.